# About a sum involving factorials.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form

I would like to know if there is a closed form of $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{4^{k}}{\left(2k\right)!\left(n-k\right)!^{2}}.$$ Wolfram gives a strange closed form and, i.e., $$\frac{16^{n}\left(2n-\frac{1}{2}\right)!}{\sqrt{\pi}\left(2n!\right)^{2}}$$ and I'm not sure is right. If it's so, I have no idea how to prove it. Is it right? And how to prove this identity? Any help would be appreciate! Thank you.

Comment: You ask whether there is a closed form, and then you write that Wolfram gives a closed form, thereby answering your own question. Next!

Comment: @GerryMyerson I would know hot to prove it! And what Wolfram wrote seems strange to me.

Comment: Then why not share the big secret of what Wolfram gave you?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I really don't understand these ironic comments. However, I'll write what Wolfram gives.

Comment: I think what he is ask is if Wolfram is right - it probably is, or else if there is a simpler form that what it writes.

Comment: @FundThmCalculus no, Gerry was referring to the initial edit. Elajan asked if there was a closed form and said that Wolfram gave one, but didn't say what Wolfram claimed it was until Gerry direction asked it.

Comment: @FundThmCalculus Yes, both. And how to prove that identity.

Comment: Loor for  the recurrence form  of the sum like sister céline algoritmo

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you, too, have come across [Jack's question from yesterday.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1304589/an-identity-involving-the-bessel-function-of-the-first-kind-j-0)
Assuming the validty of his identity, your sum, which is the convolution (Cauchy product) formed when multiplying
$\cos(1)$ and $\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!^2 4^k}$
is equal to $$\frac{(4n)!}{(2n)!^{3}}$$

Comment: I hadn't seen that question. So is it true that $$\frac{16^{n}\left(2n-\frac{1}{2}\right)!}{\sqrt{\pi}\left(2n\right)!^{2}} = \frac {\left(4n\right)!}{\left(2n\right)!^{3}}?$$

Comment: Indeed, put $z=2n+\frac{1}{2}$ in the Gamma function [duplication formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem)